# SQLite: select max index for each group

Tags: sqlite

What I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT MAX(index), scr FROM history WHERE state = "TQA" GROUP BY scr
```

So, for every 'scr' in the table, I want a row showing the maximum index where the 'state' of that row = 'TQA'.
For some reason this gives me a syntax error near "index".

Comment: that's a keyword. please see: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html for many possible solutions / workarounds. i am voting to close for simple typographical issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite. If you want to use that as a field name, you'll need to quote it;

```
SELECT MAX("index"), scr FROM history WHERE state = "TQA" GROUP BY scr
```